# Symfony2, Doctrine2, EntityManager disable last actions

Tags: loops, symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

We have

```
foreach ($rwst as $row)
{
    $loopData = XmlFunctions::getXmlAttrAsArray($row);
    if (!$loopData)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $oCharacters = new XmlAccountCharacters();
    $oCharacters
            ->setKeyID($this->keyID)
            ->setCharacterID($loopData['characterID'])
            ->setCharacterName($loopData['name'])
            ->setCorporationID($loopData['corporationID'])
            ->setCorporationName($loopData['corporationName']);

    $this->sEntityManager->persist($oCharacters);
}

$this->sEntityManager->flush();
```

Point is that when we will have FALSE on

```
$loopData
```

we will exit from current function. But. Image we will have false on second item in foreach, so the first Entity will be persisted to EntityNamager. How can I get it out there? Because next (even in another service\controller) ->flush() will save it, and we don't want it.

Comment: you want to undo the persist call ? you should only call persist if you really want to save

Comment: not it's not, try it yourself, as i said no matter from which controller flush() will be called - it will insert to db our entity.

Comment: as a simple example try to persist in one service and then call flush in another, entity from first one, will be inserted

Comment: jeah thats the desired behavior so you dont have to flush and query the database if you edit multiple entities in multiple services. what is wrong with that ? you should just only call persist if you want a new entity and definitely save it to database... if an entity is already persisted and therefore managed by doctrine ... you can even ommit the persist call and calling flush will save the entity aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is explicit transactions. Have a look at the [Doctrine-documentation](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-2-explicitly). Basically your code should look like this:

```
$this->sEntityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
try {
    foreach ($rwst as $row) {
        $loopData = XmlFunctions::getXmlAttrAsArray($row);
        if (!$loopData) {
            throw new SomeException();
        }
        \\ the rest of your code
        $this->sEntityManager->persist($oCharacters);
    }
    $this->sEntityManager->flush();
    $this->sEntityManager->getConnection()->commit();
    return true;
} catch (SomeException $e) {
    $this->sEntityManager->getConnection()->rollback();
    $this->sEntityManager->close();
}
return false;
```

Comment: good example but it's transaction, and i don't need it atm, anyway i found my answer

Answer (score 0):

As always asnwer is much simplier I could imagine. =\

```
if(!$loopData)
{
    $this->sEntityManager->clear()
    return false;
}
```

And all persisted entities would be detached from doctrine, so they won't be inserted\updated.
or for single entity

```
$this->sEntityManager->detach($entity);
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html